# Парсинг файла плейлиста m3u8 python дубль2

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Возникли дополнительные трудности: модератор плейлиста изменил формат. Теперь в некоторых частях неизмененного листа появляется вот такое:

```
#EXTINF:0 group-title="Кино",Мужское кино(Резерв)2
#EXTVLCOPT:http-user-agent=SmartLabs
http://46.173.56.71:81/udp/224.10.10.83:1234
```

вместо

```
#EXTINF:0 group-title="Кино",Мужское кино(Резерв)2
http://46.173.56.71:81/udp/224.10.10.83:1234
```

Конечный же результат должен иметь вид:

```
#EXTINF:0,Мужское кино(Резерв)2
#EXTGRP:Кино
http://46.173.56.71:81/udp/224.10.10.83:1234
```

Но при новых изменениях выходит так:

```
#EXTINF:0,Мужское кино(Резерв)2
#EXTGRP:Кино
#EXTVLCOPT:http-user-agent=SmartLabs
http://46.173.56.71:81/udp/224.10.10.83:1234
```

Плеер выдает ошибку, потому что не понимает 3-ю строку. 
Нужно ее убрать, если она есть.

Не хотелось бы городить огород с лишними файлами. Могу сделать так. Хотелось бы сразу с помощью регулярных выражений все сделать. Вот работающий кусок.

```
import requests
import datetime
import re
from pathlib import Path

login = 'login'  # Логин для формирования ссылки для скачивания
password = 'password'  # Пароль для формирования ссылки для скачивания
# Без каналов 18+
url = 'http://ssylka.com'   
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0'}   

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
with open('test.m3u8', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.text)

p = Path(r'test.m3u8')
data = p.read_text(encoding='utf-8')
pat = r'(#EXTINF:[^\s+])\s+group-title=\"([^\"]*)\",(.*)'

now = datetime.datetime.now()

out = Path(r'playlist' + now.strftime('_%d%m%Y_%H%M') + '.m3u8')
out.write_text(re.sub(pat, r'\1,\3\n#EXTGRP:\2', data))

web = Path(r'playlist_web.m3u8')
web.write_text(re.sub(pat, r'\1,\3\n#EXTGRP:\2', data))
print('Смотри файлы в папке со скриптом')
```

Comment: удалить строку #EXTVLCOPT:http-user-agent=SmartLabs, если она есть.

Comment: Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным. Опишите, как вы получаете данные, на чем их хотите обрабатывать, и для средства обработки уже сформулируйте правило по которому что-то хотите удалять. То есть для вопроса не важно плеер это или что. Важно что у вас на входе, и что вы хотите получить на выходе. *вижу правку, с ней лучше*

Comment: Вопрос подправил. Код рабочий.

Comment: Не то. Формат ввода- вывода не тот.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def flt_m3u(data):
    flt_pat = r'^(?:#EXTM3U |#EXTINF:|https?:|rtmp[setp]?:)[^\r\n]*[\r\n]'
    return ''.join(re.findall(flt_pat, data, flags=re.M))

def parse_m3u(data):
    pat = r'(#EXTINF:[^\s+])\s+group-title=\"([^\"]*)\",(.*)'
    return re.sub(pat, r'\1,\3\n#EXTGRP:\2', data)

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
out = Path(r'playlist' + now.strftime('_%d%m%Y_%H%M') + '.m3u8')
out.write_text(parse_m3u(flt_m3u(r.text)), encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Ну, если честно, это эмоции. Спасибо Вам. Выручили второй раз. Никак не дойду до регулярок. Работа, семья. Времени не остается.